# How to use the FlowTextView library and Actionbarsherlock fragments together

Tags: android

I am using the library from this page in my project: https://code.google.com/p/android-flowtextview/

And as you can see in the method setText in my code, it runs the code to set the text for the view. But when I run the app on my phone, it crashes, showing a NullPointerException

Does anyone know how to get this working correctly? Thanks. (I also have seperate class files for the fragments, and the code for the first one is below the main code.

Main code:

```
package com.cw1998.app.ref;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.pagesuite.flowtext.FlowTextView;

public class Faction extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    ViewPager mViewPager;
    TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;
    TextView tabCenter;
    TextView tabText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
        mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);

        setContentView(mViewPager);
        ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);

        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Fragment 1dsa"),
                Faction_tab_1.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Fragment 2sad"),
                Faction_tab_2.class, null);
        setText();
    }

    public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
            ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
        private final Context mContext;
        private final ActionBar mActionBar;
        private final ViewPager mViewPager;
        private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

        static final class TabInfo {
            private final Class<?> clss;
            private final Bundle args;

            TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
                clss = _class;
                args = _args;
            }
        }

        public TabsAdapter(SherlockFragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager) {
            super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
            mContext = activity;
            mActionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
            mViewPager = pager;
            mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        }

        public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
            TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
            tab.setTag(info);
            tab.setTabListener(this);
            mTabs.add(info);
            mActionBar.addTab(tab);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mTabs.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
            return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(),
                    info.args);
        }

        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }

        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            Object tag = tab.getTag();
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++) {
                if (mTabs.get(i) == tag) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                }
            }
        }

        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }

        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }
    }

    public void setText() {
        FlowTextView tv;
        tv = (FlowTextView) findViewById(R.id.tab_1_text);
        tv.setText("Testing"); // using plain text
        tv.invalidate(); // call this to render the text
    }
}
```

Fragment classes code:

```
package com.cw1998.app.ref;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

public class Faction_tab_1 extends SherlockFragment
{

  @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.faction_grineer_enemies, container, false);

  return view;
 }

}
```

Comment: do you have a logcat of the NPE?

Comment: Yes. But I'm no longer on my computer to get it. I also got this problem solved, so I will post a solution here tomorrow.